# Getting very low accuracy on my CNN Model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a built CNN model in pytorch and i am getting very less accuracy on it.

```
# model building
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #covolution layers
        self.conv=nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3,16,3,1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),

            nn.Conv2d(16,32,3,1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),

            nn.Conv2d(32,64,3,1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        )
        #fully connected layers
        self.fc=nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.LazyLinear(64),
            nn.Linear(64,128),
            nn.Linear(128,6)
        )
    #forward pass
    def forward(self,x):
        x=self.fc(self.conv(x))
        return x
device=torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model=CNN().to(device)
criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.01)

#trainig Network
    epochs=10
    print('Training Started...')
    for i in range(epochs):
        tr_sample=0
        tr_correct=0
        for b,(image,label) in enumerate(train_loader):
            image=image.to(device)
            label=label.to(device)
            y_pred=model.forward(image)
            loss=criterion(y_pred,label)
            _,predicted=torch.max(y_pred,1)
            tr_sample+=label.size(0)
            tr_correct+=(predicted==label).sum().item()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        trn_acc=100*(tr_correct/tr_sample)
    
        with torch.no_grad():
            n_samples=0
            n_correct=0
            for image,label in test_loader:
                image=image.to(device)
                label=label.to(device)
                y_eval=model.forward(image)
                _,predicted=torch.max(y_eval,1)
                n_samples+=label.size(0)
                n_correct+=(predicted==label).sum().item()
            acc=100*n_correct/n_samples
        print(f'Epoch: {i} | loss: {loss.item()} | train accuracy:{trn_acc:.4f} % | test accuracy: {acc:.4f} %')
    print('Training Finished !')
```

Here is the glimpse of accuracy which I am receiving.
[image]

How do i improve the accuracy of my model? I tried already tuning parameters but nothing seems to be working out. I am getting much better accuracy for same layers on tensorflow.

Comment: You can add `BatchNorm2d` after each convolution layer. If the same model works better in tensorflow, you may want to check that you coded the evaluation part correctly.

Comment: I don't know CNN as well as other ML methodologies, so it's hard for me to offer guidance on this specific topic, but maybe this link will help you get going in the right direction. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/learn-image-classification-cnn-convolutional-neural-networks-3-datasets/